# ActiveMQ Artemis cluster doesn't work with Docker Swarm overlay network?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm, activemq-artemis

I have deployed an ActiveMQ Artemis HA cluster as shared storage cluster (one is master, one is slave). My cluster was working fine with standalone Docker (deploying with "docker-compose up") using bridge network, but it's not working with Docker Swarm using default overlay network (Swarm cannot use the overlay network). It seems likes container hostname cannot resolve each other. The error was something like waiting from broadcast ...

Do anyone ever face the issue like this before? Or any recommendation?

**This is my compose for docker swarm**

```
version: '3.8'
networks:
  backend:
services:
  artemis1:
    image: witwickey/artemis-centos:2.28.0
    hostname: artemis1
    ports:
      - "61617:61616"
      - "5673:5672"
      - "5446:5445"
      - "1884:1883"
      - "8161:8161"
    environment:
      ARTEMIS_USER: admin
      ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: admin
      ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "false"
    volumes:
       - ./master/artemis-instance:/var/lib/artemis-instance
    networks:
      - backend
  artemis2:
    image: witwickey/artemis-centos:2.28.0
    hostname: artemis2
    ports:
      - "61618:61616"
      - "5674:5672"
      - "5447:5445"
      - "1885:1883"
      - "8162:8161"
    environment:
      ARTEMIS_USER: admin
      ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: admin
      ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "false"
    volumes:
       - ./slave/artemis-instance:/var/lib/artemis-instance
    networks:
      - backend
volumes:
     artemis-data:
       external: true
```

I deployed docker swarm and got the same error from artemis2 as below

```
2023-07-03 23:27:23,866 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server version 2.28.0
2023-07-03 23:27:23,918 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: backup Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2023-07-03 23:27:23,939 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241003: Starting embedded web server
2023-07-03 23:27:24,044 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221032: Waiting to become backup node
2023-07-03 23:27:24,048 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221033: ** got backup lock
2023-07-03 23:27:24,158 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
2023-07-03 23:27:24,410 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1073741824
2023-07-03 23:27:24,844 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2023-07-03 23:27:24,845 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2023-07-03 23:27:24,848 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2023-07-03 23:27:24,849 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2023-07-03 23:27:24,849 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2023-07-03 23:27:24,851 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2023-07-03 23:27:25,082 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221109: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Backup Server version 2.28.0 [df47a27d-18cd-11ee-8d6a-02420a001203] started, waiting live to fail before it gets active
2023-07-03 23:27:25,476 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2023-07-03 23:27:25,580 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2023-07-03 23:27:26,109 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2023-07-03 23:27:26,155 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2023-07-03 23:27:26,160 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.15.0
2023-07-03 23:27:26,171 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2023-07-03 23:27:26,190 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginRedirectFilter] Hawtio loginRedirectFilter is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2023-07-03 23:27:26,207 INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
2023-07-03 23:27:26,213 INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/var/lib/artemis-instance/./etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2023-07-03 23:27:26,395 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8161
2023-07-03 23:27:26,398 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console/jolokia
2023-07-03 23:27:26,400 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console
2023-07-03 23:27:35,096 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222137: Unable to announce backup, retrying
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ219012: Timed out waiting to receive initial broadcast from cluster
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.executeDiscovery(ServerLocatorImpl.java:765) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:653) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:547) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:526) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.BackupManager$BackupConnector$1.run(BackupManager.java:273) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:57) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:32) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:68) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
2023-07-03 23:27:45,613 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222137: Unable to announce backup, retrying
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ219012: Timed out waiting to receive initial broadcast from cluster
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.executeDiscovery(ServerLocatorImpl.java:765) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:653) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:547) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:526) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.BackupManager$BackupConnector$1.run(BackupManager.java:273) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:57) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:32) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:68) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
```

I tried deploy on 1 node and 3 nodes Docker Swarm, the error still the same on artemis2

Here is the `broker.xml` from artemis1:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>artemis1</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>


      <!-- if you want to retain your journal uncomment this following configuration.

      This will allow your system to keep 7 days of your data, up to 10G. Tweak it accordingly to your use case and capacity.

      it is recommended to use a separate storage unit from the journal for performance considerations.

      <journal-retention-directory period="7" unit="DAYS" storage-limit="10G">data/retention</journal-retention-directory>

      You can also enable retention by using the argument journal-retention on the `artemis create` command -->



      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 1.21 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 828000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>828000</journal-buffer-timeout>


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->



    <connectors>
        <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
        <connector name="artemis">tcp://artemis1:61616</connector>
    </connectors>



      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


      <page-sync-timeout>828000</page-sync-timeout>


      <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit. This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

      The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
      You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

      <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size> -->

      <!-- the maximum number of messages accepted before entering full address mode.
           if global-max-size is specified the full address mode will be specified by whatever hits it first. -->
      <global-max-messages>-1</global-max-messages>

      <acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->
         <!-- amqpDuplicateDetection: If you are not using duplicate detection, set this to false
                                      as duplicate detection requires applicationProperties to be parsed on the server. -->
         <!-- amqpMinLargeMessageSize: Determines how many bytes are considered large, so we start using files to hold their data.
                                       default: 102400, -1 would mean to disable large mesasge control -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->


         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://artemis1:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://artemis1:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://artemis1:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://artemis1:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://artemis1:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>


      <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>

      <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
         </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>0</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>


      <ha-policy>
         <shared-store>
            <master>
               <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
            </master>
         </shared-store>
      </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>

            <!-- if max-size-bytes and max-size-messages were both enabled, the system will enter into paging
                 based on the first attribute to hits the maximum value -->
            <!-- limit for the address in bytes, -1 means unlimited -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>

            <!-- limit for the address in messages, -1 means unlimited -->
            <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>

            <!-- the size of each file on paging. Notice we keep files in memory while they are in use.
                 Lower this setting if you have too many queues in memory. -->
            <page-size-bytes>10M</page-size-bytes>

            <!-- limit how many messages are read from paging into the Queue. -->
            <max-read-page-messages>-1</max-read-page-messages>

            <!-- limit how much memory is read from paging into the Queue. -->
            <max-read-page-bytes>20M</max-read-page-bytes>

            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
            <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>


      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->

   </core>
</configuration>
```

And the `broker.xml` from artemis2 was changed a little bit as below

```xml
      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <slave>
            </slave>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>
```

And changed hostname to artemis2

Comment: Hi, Please provide the compose file or any additional info that can be useful to reproduce the problem and the exact error log, try to avoid the `error was something like` when you can add the exact log.

Comment: I'm sorry. I already add the information above.

Comment: Does the Docker Swarm overlay network support UDP multicast? I ask because you've configured the brokers to use UDP multicast for cluster node discovery.

Comment: As far as I understand it, overlay networks do not support multicast. I think my configuration is using TCP. Could you please pointing out where it uses UDP multicast?

Thank you